# In Mongoose , 'populate' function is not populating the field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

I had defined two schemas with one to many relationship i.e between blog and comments. Whenever a specific blog get called I want to populate that blog with respective comments.

## **blog.js**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const Schema=mongoose.Schema

const blogschema=new Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
       
    },
    body:{
        type:String,
        
    },
    author:{
        type:String,
    },
    date:{
        type:Date
    },
    comments:[
        {
            type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'Comment'
        }
    
    ]

})
const Blog=mongoose.model('Blog',blogschema)

module.exports=Blog;
```

**comment.js**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const {Schema}=mongoose

const commentschema=new Schema({
    comment:{
        type:String,
    }
})

const Comment=mongoose.model('Comment',commentschema)
module.exports=Comment
```

**index.js**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const {Schema}=mongoose

const commentschema=new Schema({
    comment:{
        type:String,
    }
})

const Comment=mongoose.model('Comment',commentschema)
module.exports=Comment
```

I was expecting that the blog's comments field will get populate, so that I can display it later.
I am trying to print the blog with comments in the console but it is showing
`

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63f847e4d4d62645cdae95c9"),
  title: 'ms dhoni is shit',
  body: 'yes he is',
  author: 'aditya',
  __v: 11,
  comments: [
    { _id: new ObjectId("640ca290b2c3bc12c7bd8064"), __v: 0 },
    { _id: new ObjectId("640ca2b9b2c3bc12c7bd806a"), __v: 0 },
    { _id: new ObjectId("640ca5e05f2eed687208ef46"), __v: 0 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The code of the `index.js` may be wrong. How did you use `.populate()` method?